# ¿Porque se detiene mi app al utilizar esta linea de codigo?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

Este es el código de mi clase base de datos.

```
public class SQLite_OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public SQLite_OpenHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE t_emisiones(pais TEXT primary key, emision REAL);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE t_emisiones");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Aquí es donde se detiene mi app, cuando llega a los (db.execSQL).

```
SQLite_OpenHelper dbhelp = new SQLite_OpenHelper(this,"emisores_paises", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelp.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO t_emisiones VALUES('colombia', 0.205)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO t_emisiones VALUES('espana', 0.388)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO t_emisiones VALUES('mexico', 0.582)");
    db.close();
```

He estado programando en Android Studio y soy muy novato, lo que quiero realizar es una base de datos con valores que yo agregue como constantes y luego los pueda leer para trabajar con ellos pero al agregar la linea de código para insertar datos se detiene la app.

PD: sugerencias por si es mejor trabajarlo con arreglos que por base de datos.

Comment: Buenas! No copies capturas del codigo, simplemente transcribelo. Y en que linea exactamente se detiene?

Comment: @ZottoSL De esa manera?. Lo siento, soy nuevo usando la plataforma

Comment: @KevinMartinez es importante revisar el LogCat ahí se muestra información acerca del problema, de otra forma las razones del error son varias.

Comment: @Jorgesys Podrias ayudarme con eso? Porfavor

Comment: Revisa el LogCat que errores se muestran Escribir y ver registros con Logcat @KevinMartinez

Answer (score 1):

Es importante hagas uso del [LogCat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) para tener más información acerca de algún problema en tu aplicación, de otra forma en ocasiones las causas de cierre pueden ser diversas y en ocasiones perderás demasiado tiempo tratando de resolver el problema:

[Escribir y ver registros con Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat)

Un error que noto a simple vista es al crear las tablas de tu base de datos, la definicion de la tabla no debe estar junto a la de los campos:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    //db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE t_emisiones(pais TEXT primary key, emision REAL);");
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE t_emisiones (pais TEXT primary key, emision REAL);");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes investigar sobre los bloques de código de "**try catch**" que van a evitar que tu programa se detenga, pero ojo aguas con abusar de ellos por que después es difícil depurar el código.

```
try{
    SQLite_OpenHelper dbhelp = new SQLite_OpenHelper(this,"emisores_paises", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbhelp.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO t_emisiones VALUES('colombia', 0.205)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO t_emisiones VALUES('espana', 0.388)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO t_emisiones VALUES('mexico', 0.582)");
}catch (Exception e){
   //Aqui muestra los errores
   //En caso de que tu programa no pueda ejecutar las lineas de arriba
   Log.d("tag", "El error es" + e);
}finally {
   //Finalmente cierra la conexión después de realizar tus tareas.
   db.close();
}
```

Te dejo más información al respecto de como usar los try catch
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html

Pero te recuerdo que esto solo es para que tu programa pueda continuar, esto solo hará que no truene.